# How to run Several Class files parallely using Selenium + TestNG

Tags: selenium, grid, webdriver, controls, testng

I have a Package with several Test class every class is a test case, it would count 500-600,

My question is how to run parallel instance of individual Classess , I know that to specify in TESTNG XmL and metnioning all classes with parallel='Classess' but still it is time consuming to mention all classess in the XML and would be difficult to maintain.

Any alternative solutions ?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by making xml file

```
 <!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">

<suite name="Suite to test Wordpress Post Tag Category">

<test name="testing Test_Base">
 <classes>
 <class name="testWordpress.Test_Base" ></class>
 </classes>
</test>

&nbsp;

<test name="testing post">
 <classes>
 <class name="testWordpress.Test_post" ></class>
 </classes>
</test>

<test name="testing Tag">
 <classes>
 <class name="testWordpress.Test_tag" ></class>
 </classes>
</test>

<test name="testing Category">
 <classes>
 <class name="testWordpress.Test_Category" ></class>
 </classes>
</test>

</suite>
```

To learn this stuff from scratch Please check out this [link](http://tinyurl.com/blt75bf)

Answer (score 0):

One way can be to specify the package instead of classes and set parallel to classes.  This would invoke all classes inside the package in parallel.

Comment: It is not necessary to give Class tag in XML ? I will try this.

Comment: Nope.. It's not necessary..you can give a packages tag inside test.  Refer to the second eg. Here http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#testng-xml